# Что делать, если нужен доступ к переменной ,которая инициализирована в другом классе, а создать экземпляр того класса нельзя

Tags: java, ооп

В связи с некой архитектурой , получить экземпляр класса в котором инициализирована переменная не могу. Могу эту переменную объявить как статик. Но есть ли какие то другие способы?

Из этого класса `MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`  создается поток `MainThread(getHolder(), this);`  переменная инициализируется в потоке. В классе `public class Chronometer` , который ни от чего не наследуется, экземпляр потока получить не могу, так как нет getHolder() . Как получить доступ к переменной через статик или пользоваться интерфейсом или есть еще какие то более адекватные способы?  Сама переменная хранит время в наносекундах и изменяется довольно таки редко.

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated");
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

.

```
class MainThread extends Thread {

     static int start;

}
```

.

```
public class Chronometer {

   start = 123; //Какими способами я могу обратиться к этой переменной ,если ее объявить не как статик? Экземпляр класса MainThread создать не могу.

}
```

Comment: Сколько создается экземпляров данного класса?

Comment: довольно сложно понять, какая у вас архитектура. добавьте побольше кода.

Comment: Artem Konovalov, MainThread это класс наследуемый от Tread и я создаю один его экземпляр.

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, добавил код необходимый ,чтобы понять вопрос. В принципе на словах я тоже, как мне кажется, достаточно понятно объяснил, но что то меня никто не понял...

Comment: Почему Хронометр должен знать про какую-то там переменную? Если это таймстамп начала отсчёта - передайте его в конструктор Хронометра.

Comment: В общем вывод такой, что когда я создавал архитектуру я не предполагал как буду реализовывать подобный хронометр. Т.к. переменная, которая нужна хронометру инициализируется в потоке, её приходится делать статик, так как при постановке на паузе поток уничтожается, а статик переменная будет жить. Поэтому в связи с архитектурой статик удобное решение. К этому я пришел,когда попытался сделать как вы сказали, через конструктор передавать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо выкинуть объект из потока? Как самое простое решение java.util.concurrent.Exchanger
Если я правильно проблему понял.

Comment: не совсем понял , что значит "выкинуть" . В потоке объявляется переменная, доступ к которой я должен получить из другого класса, чтобы присваивать этой переменной значение. Вопрос в том, как я могу это сделать. Если переменную объявить как статик, то проблем с обращением нет. Но правильно ли использовать статик с этой целью?    Обычно, чтобы получить доступ к переменной из другого класса, создаю экземпляр этого класса и через него обращаюсь, но в этом случае экземпляр класса создать не получается.

Comment: У тебя есть 2 потока, которые используют 1 переменную. Что бы у обоих потоков были ссылки на эту переменную надо либо инициализировать ее до запуска потоков и передать ссылку в поток (что собственно ты и делаешь, объявляя переменную static, можно просто до потоков ее объявить как переменную объекта, а не класса). Либо передать во время исполнения, для этого Exchanger.

Comment: а "выкинуть" это я имел ввиду наружу передать из треда

Comment: Как переменную объекта я её объявить не могу , так как поток уничтожается при постановке игры на паузу и создается новый при возобновлении игры , в этом случае и переменная моя будет терять своё значение.  Появился такой вопрос: Если статик объявлена в классе потока, значит она создается вне конструктора, но в какой момент ?после чего?  Вопрос появляется потому ,переменная вроде создается когда дело доходит до запуска экземпляра класса, но при уничтожении этого экземпляра сама переменная не умирает.

Comment: @Turalllb Если честно, то считаю, что объявление глобальных (`static`) переменных - крах ООП дизайна приложения. Судя по вопросам, в понимании концепции объектов есть пробелы, я бы посоветовал что-нибудь почитать по ООП. Для начинающих очень [Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19665827/) хорош. Static переменная является переменной класса, а не объекта, поэтому инициализируется при загрузке класса в perm-gen classloader-ом.

Comment: Вот вот , это я и хотел услышать ,что существует некий perm-gen classloader, который перед запуском первого класса уже знает о всех классах, ищет в них переменные классов и инициализирует . А насчет пробелов я в курсе, но ими займусь конкретно после того как первую игру допишу, я решил сразу к практике без теории. Тоже не плохой вариант изучения, если хочется сразу хоть каких то наглядных результатов

Comment: Exchanger тоже как вариант решения моего вопроса, только интересно он может между главным потоком и доп потоком обмениваться? думаю что да.

Comment: Потоки равнозначны с момента их создания и запуска (если не демоны, конечно). perm-gen - область памяти jvm, classloader - объект, занимающийся загрузкой классов ("в perm-gen classloader-ом" это "куда кем")